# Roman type in MS Mincho/SimSun

Tags: font-recommendation, typefaces, type-theory

Some time ago I had drawn attention to the font MS Mincho, namely
its Latin set. Same (or very close) Latin set is used also in SimSun font and some others with asian titles.

I have to say, I'm really astonished by the quality of letters and overall stroke balance. Especially I want to emphasize that I notice outstanding legibility of this font. 
There is a monospaced version - Mincho, and a normal (proportional) version  - PMincho.

Here are examples:

[image]

I personally find particular letters of Mincho (first line in the image) 
are better crafted than in PMincho, such as e.g. bowls in "p", more prominent **"r"** and **"i"**. 
So in PMincho some of them became worse, namely **"i"** is
too narrow, and in general -- a bit too dense by default.
So, yes I am criticising PMincho for having some drawbacks.
(Please note that I am not talking about monospaced vs proportional, 
but rather features of some letters. In the image, I have adjusted spacing of Mincho manually to make the comparison)

I became really curious, because this typeface seems to provide better 
**readability** than any others I have seen before, particularly some features
of Mincho's letters, like I said.

It would be really interesting to know:

- who is the designer of MS Mincho (Latin set)? Any sources, historical notes?
- is this letter design (Mincho Latin) very original or derived from some very close brother?
- if there are other types **very** close to Mincho, please make examples. 
  Namely exactly as Mincho, only with few letters adjusted (Mm, Ww).

Probably there is even a separate term for this typeface group?
I know that it is classic/roman group, but try googling "classic roman"!
One fairly similar font on my computer is Times New Roman, but with other stroke style and width.

Comment: MS Gothic and MS Mincho were designed by [Ricoh](http://industry.ricoh.com/font/knowledge/fontknowledge01.html). Unfortunately, I cannot find much info in english, but I think searching in japanese you will find many more resources. BTW, there are a lot of japanese typefaces made by vendors as Morisawa, DynaComWare or Iwata that have serif latin characters similar to the MS Mincho ones.